# Code-review поиск одинаковых слов в списках

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода

господа. Полагаю, данный код можно/нужно сократить, возможно использовать библиотеки Pandas. Ковыряла, по итогу, дельного ничего не нашла. 
Код реализует вывод слов из второго списка, при условии, что они не совпадают со словом из первого. Огромное спасибо!

```py
    text_robot = ['попытаемся найти соску', 'надоедливый блогер', 'капитан очевиднасть', 'корректное предложение'] 
    text_human = ['попытаемся найти сосиску', 'блогер обычный', 'капитан очевидность', 'корректное предложение']
        itog_termin_list = []

        for sentence in text_human: 
            if sentence not in text_robot:
                dobavlenie_elementa = text_robot[text_human.index(sentence)]
                sentence_new = sentence
                if len(dobavlenie_elementa.split(' ')) > len(sentence.split(' ')):
                    for i in range(len(dobavlenie_elementa.split(' ')) - len(sentence.split(' '))):
                        sentence_new = sentence_new + ' trash'
                else: 
                    len(sentence.split(' ')) - len(dobavlenie_elementa.split(' '))
                    for i in range(len(sentence.split(' ')) - len(dobavlenie_elementa.split(' '))):
                        dobavlenie_elementa = dobavlenie_elementa + ' trash'
                for word in sentence_new.split(' '):
                    if word not in text_robot[text_human.index(sentence)].split(' '): # индексы (убрать)
                        itog_human = word
                        try:
                            itog_robot = dobavlenie_elementa.split(' ')[sentence_new.split(' ').index(word)]
                            if itog_human != itog_robot and itog_human != 'trash':
                                if itog_human not in itog_termin_list:
                                    itog_termin_list.append(itog_human)
                        except:
                            print('ou, shit')
        print(itog_termin_list)
```

> ['сосиску', 'обычный', 'очевидность']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так

```
def getWords(lst):
    res=[]
    for element in lst:
        temp=[x for x in element.split()]
        res=res+temp;
    return res

word_robot=getWords(text_robot)
word_human=getWords(text_human)

for word in word_human:
    if word not in word_robot:
        print(word)
```

Если нужно чтобы слова не повторялись

```
result=[]

for word in word_human:
    if word not in word_robot and word not in result:
        result.append(word)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
res = []

for rob, hum in zip(text_robot, text_human):
    res.extend(set(hum.split()) - set(rob.split()))
```

---

результат:

```
In [21]: res
Out[21]: ['сосиску', 'обычный', 'очевидность']
```

Comment: Наиболее pythonic way!

Answer (score 1):

А вот ещё по приколу в одну строчку вариант, на основе решения @MaxU:

```
print(sum([list(set(hum.split()) - set(rob.split())) for rob, hum in zip(text_robot, text_human)], []))
```

- for rob, hum in zip(text_robot, text_human) - перебираем пары предложений
- set(hum.split()) - set(rob.split()) - берём набор тех слов, которые есть во втором предложении, но нет в первом
- list(...) - превращаем set в list, это нужно дальше
- sum(..., []) - делаем из списка списков слов просто список слов

Answer (score 0):

или так

```py
def search(text_human, text_robot):
    sent_r = []
    for j in [i.split() for i in text_robot]:
        sent_r.extend(j)
    for sent in range(len(text_human)):
        sent_h = text_human[sent].split()
        for s in sent_h:
            if s not in sent_r:
                yield s
```

```
print(list(search(text_human, text_robot)))
```

> ['сосиску', 'обычный', 'очевидность']

Comment: text_robot = ['попытаемся найти сосиску', 'надоедливый блогер'] 
text_human = ['попытаемся найти сосиску', 'блогер обычный сосиску'] На этих данных выдает неверный результат

Comment: @becouse вы взяли разные по длине предложения, что не оговаривалось в условии - не валите!

Comment: text_robot = ['попытаемся найти сосиску', 'надоедливый блогер'] text_human = ['попытаемся найти сосиску', 'блюгер сосиску'] На этих данных выдает неверный результат

Comment: @becouse а что неверного?

Comment: 'сосиску' встречается в первом списке

Comment: @becouse этого не было в примере автора, но пусть

Comment: вы не верно поняли условие. " вывод слов из второго списка, при условии, что они не совпадают со словом из первого" Это не значит, что в элементах массива с одинаковым номером.

Comment: @becouse исправил

Answer (score 0):

```
lst1=[]
for sent in text_robot:
    lst1=lst1+sent.split()
lst2=[]
for sent in text_human:
    lst2=lst2+sent.split()
print(set(lst2).difference(set(lst1)) )
```

Результат: 
    {'очевидность', 'обычный', 'сосиску'}